# Are there examples that explain how to upload files to ACC and BIM 360 Sheets

Tags: autodesk-forge

I’m primary a C# Revit API developer, I’m trying to get into Forge/APS development. I can go thru and use the examples for APS that are in Visual Studio but if they are not, it’s difficult for me to understand the logic and implement. One example is: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/sheets/upload-sheets/. How should I proceed? Are there any examples and/or how should I approach this on my own to proceed?

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in simply uploading design files to BIM360 or ACC, I would recommend following the standard Data Management tutorial: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/. These tutorials use "curl" - a command-line tool for sending HTTP requests to our web services. You can use other HTTP clients as well, for example, [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/).

And finally, when you're ready to start developing your own application, you can use our [C# SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge) which makes the HTTP calls for you. For example, instead of manually sending an HTTP request to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/<projectId>/items` to create a new version of a design, you would simply call the [PostItem](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ItemsApi.md#postitem) method.